# CodeIgniter Strange URL Routing Issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Ok. So I changed the routing by adding this rule in the routes.php file:

```
$route['tools/(:any)'] = "b/view/$1";
```

However, when I visit http://mywebsite.com/tools/toolid, I get the following error:

> A PHP ERROR WAS ENCOUNTERED
>
> SEVERITY: NOTICE
>
> MESSAGE: TRYING TO GET PROPERTY OF NON-OBJECT
>
> FILENAME: VIEWS/LISTING_PAGE.PHP
>
> LINE NUMBER: 64

So the code on line 64 in the LISTING_PAGE.PHP file is:

```
echo $categoryinfo->name;
```

The LISTING_PAGE.PHP is a view which is loaded by the code in the B class, specifically this line:

```
$this->load->view("listing_page", $data);
```

Now, the strange thing is, if I change the routing rule in routes.php to:

```
$route['tools/id/(:any)'] = "b/view/$1"; //I added an id 'section'
```

Then the code works without error.

The code also works perfectly if I access http://mywebsite.com/b/view/toolid.

So it appears that if there is more than one 'section' (tools/id) then the code works perfectly, if there is only one 'section'(tools/) then there is that non-object error.

Does anyone know what may cause this issue?

Comment: Is there more than one **tools/** used for routing in route.php? if its yes than its ambiguous situation for codeigniter.

Comment: there is only one rule regarding tools in the routes.php

Comment: In your controller you getting id from url ?  and than you use to get **$categoryinfo data**?

Comment: i think, problem not in route. Looking  how you set value to $categoryinfo and how give it to view. In any case its not object. For example, not defined variable. Maybe, this line doesn't executed due to some condition

Comment: id is just an arbitriary 'section' of the url that routes to the 'real' url which is b/view

Answer (score 0):

@splash58 is right
You should put:

```
echo '<pre>', var_dump($category);exit;
```

on very first line of view file just after opening php tag and see what have you got.

Comment: array (size=0)
  empty : this is the result

Comment: Have you changed variables names in opening question, because I can't see `$category variable now? You should post whole controller and routes file here so one could help you.